# Verify if the register already exeist

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I don't have much experience in using JAVA with SQL Server or any other database, so I'm having some trouble at the moment.

I have the following code:

```
public void insertProjeto(Planejado p){
   String verifica="SELECT cd_projeto FROM PROJETO WHERE cd_projeto = ?";
   String sqlInsert="INSERT INTO PROJETO (cd_projeto, ds_projeto) VALUES (?, ?)";

   String projeto = p.getProjeto();
   String nomeProjeto = p.getNomeProj();

   PreparedStatement stmt;      
   try {
      stmt = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(verifica);
      stmt.setString(1, projeto);
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();           

      if (rs.equals("") || rs.equals(null)) {
         System.out.println("------------------");
         stmt = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

         stmt.setString(1, projeto);
         stmt.setString(2, nomeProjeto);

         stmt.executeUpdate();
      }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

My goal is insert a register without duplicates, but for some reason my "if" isn't working.
Can anybody help me find out why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? What results are you observing?

Comment: I mean that the condition inside the "if" must have a logic problem or any other problem. I don't get any error message, the code simply never enter inside the "if"

Answer (score 0):

When obtaining a ResultSet, you must call its next() method to have it progress to the first row of data if any. In case there is no data in the ResultSet object, rs.next() will return false.

There are better ways to prevent duplicates on SQL tables depends on what SQL server you're using (MS SQL, MySQL etc.)

If you're using MySQL, you can make cd_projeto a primary key and call REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO, it will result in updating the record for cases it exist and inserting a new one when it doesn't.

Comment: I already a database where I have id_projeto as PK and I would take some time to make this change of PK because I'm not responsible for the database.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question. It would be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

```
try {
   stmt = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(verifica);
   stmt.setString(1, projeto);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();      

   while(!rs.next()) {
      System.out.println("------------------");
      stmt = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

      stmt.setString(1, projeto);
      stmt.setString(2, nomeProjeto);

      stmt.executeUpdate();
      break;
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't know if it's the best way to do it, but works.
Thank you for the tips